# table cell rowspan PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I would like to count duplicated order_id in array and depending on the result print rowspan on table cell. I'm not sure how to achieve this with php, any help is appreciated.

I have php array like this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 1374282003
        [status] => 1
        [mark] => Casio
        [model] => W-81
        [price] => 10.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 1374282003
        [status] => 1
        [mark] => Casio
        [model] => W-81
        [price] => 10.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 1374282573
        [status] => 1
        [mark] => Casio
        [model] => W-81
        [price] => 10.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 1374282573
        [status] => 1
        [mark] => Casio
        [model] => W-81
        [price] => 10.00
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 1374282573
        [status] => 1
        [mark] => Casio
        [model] => W-81
        [price] => 10.00
    )
```

)

I would like to use rowspan on table cell like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Order</td>
<td>Product</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td>Status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="2">1374282003</td>
  <td>Casio</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Casio</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">1374282573</td>
  <td>Casio</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Casio</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Casio</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the code for array looping

```
<?php
$rowspan = array_count_values(array_map(function($item) { return $item['order_id']; }, $result));
foreach( $result as $row) {
?>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan[$row['order_id']]"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['mark']. " " .$row['model']; ?></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><?php echo number_format($row['price'], 2, '.', ','); ?> kuna</td>
  <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: sorry, I updated first post with loop code.

Answer (score 2):

It will works,

```
function check_next_rowspan($sql_values, $checkkey, $rowspan) {
    $current_id = $sql_values[$checkkey]['id'];
    if(count($sql_values) != $checkkey+1) {
        if($sql_values[$checkkey+1]['id'] == $current_id) {
            $rowspan++;
            return check_next_rowspan($sql_values, $checkkey+1, $rowspan);
        }
    }                   
    return $rowspan;
}

function check_previous_rowspan($sql_values, $checkprevkey) {
    if($checkprevkey != 0) {
        if($sql_values[$checkprevkey]['id'] == $sql_values[$checkprevkey-1]['id']) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}   

$sql_values = array(
                    array('id'=>'1', 'value'=>'test1'),
                    array('id'=>'1', 'value'=>'test2'),
                    array('id'=>'1', 'value'=>'test3'),
                    array('id'=>'2', 'value'=>'test4'),
                    array('id'=>'3', 'value'=>'test5'),
                    array('id'=>'3', 'value'=>'test6'),
                    array('id'=>'3', 'value'=>'test7'),
                    array('id'=>'4', 'value'=>'test8'),
                    array('id'=>'4', 'value'=>'test9'),
                );
$rowspan = 1;
$tablehtml = '';
foreach($sql_values as $key => $sql_value){ 
    $tablehtml .= '<tr>';
    $current_id = $sql_value['id'];
    $rowspancount = check_next_rowspan($sql_values, $key, $rowspan);
    if($rowspancount > 1) {
        $checkprevid = check_previous_rowspan($sql_values, $key);
        if($checkprevid) {
            $tablehtml .= '<td>'. $sql_value['value'] .'</td>';
        } else {
            $tablehtml .= '<td rowspan="'.$rowspancount.'">'. $sql_value['id'] .'</td><td>'. $sql_value['value'] .'</td>';
            $rowspancount = 1;
        }
    } else {
        $checkprevid1 = check_previous_rowspan($sql_values, $key);
        if($checkprevid1) {
            $tablehtml .= '<td>'. $sql_value['value'] .'</td>';
        } else {
            $tablehtml .= '<td>'. $sql_value['id'] .'</td><td>'. $sql_value['value'] .'</td>';
        }                   
    }
    $tablehtml .= '</tr>';
}

$html = '<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                '.$tablehtml.'
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>';
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in the loop you use to populate the table data with:

```
if(in_array($item['order_id'], $tempArray))
{
    $rowspan += count($tempArray);
}
$tempArray[] = $item['order_id'];
```

Comment: This will count how many rowspan do I need. But in my code this is done with array_count_values

Comment: Try using `<td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan[$row['order_id']] ?>"><?php foreach($row['order_id'] as $oID){echo $oID.'<br />';} ?></td>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$rowspan = array_count_values(array_map(function($item) { return $item['order_id']; }, $result));
foreach( $result as $row) {
?>
<tr>
  <td rowspan="<?php echo $rowspan[$row['order_id']]"><?php echo $row['order_id']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['mark']. " " .$row['model']; ?></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><?php echo number_format($row['price'], 2, '.', ','); ?> kuna</td>
  <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Ok, in here, you have some PHP, and then it's surrounding some HTML, and then it's into some PHP, and and and. Eventually, this will make you crazy.

Start with reducing your PHP tags to just one or two per file. It's just not meant to do string processing by jumping in and out of the PHP engine. So switch to something like this:

```
<?php
$rowspan = array_count_values(array_map(function($item) { return $item['order_id']; }, $result));
foreach( $result as $row){
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td rowspan=" . $rowspan[$row['order_id']] .$row['order_id'] ."></td>\n" ;
    echo "<td><" .$row['mark']. " " .$row['model'] . "></td>\n";
    echo "<td>1</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['order_id']. "</td>";
    echo "<td><" . number_format($row['price'], 2, '.', ',') . "> kuna</td>\n";
    echo "<td><" .$row['status'] ."></td>\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    } 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$results = [
0 => [
        'order_id'=> '1374282003',
        'status'=> 1,
        'mark'=> 'Casio',
        'model'=> 'W-81',
        'price'=> 10.00,
    ],
1=> [
        'order_id'=> '1374282003',
        'status'=> 1,
        'mark'=> 'Casio',
        'model'=> 'W-81',
        'price'=> 10.00,
    ],
2=> [
        'order_id'=> '1374282573',
        'status'=> 1,
        'mark'=> 'Casio',
        'model'=> 'W-81',
        'price'=> '10.00',
    ],
3=> [
        'order_id'=> '1374282573',
        'status'=> 1,
        'mark'=> 'Casio',
        'model'=> 'W-81',
        'price'=> 10.00,
    ],
4=> [
        'order_id'=> '1374282573',
        'status'=> 1,
        'mark'=> 'Casio',
        'model'=> 'W-81',
        'price'=> 10.00,
    ],
];

$pedidos = [];

foreach($results as $key =>$pedido){
  $pedidos[$pedido['order_id']][] = $pedido;
  $count = count($pedidos[$pedido['order_id']]);
  $pedidos[$pedido['order_id']][0]['rowspan'] = $count;
}
?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>Order id</th>
    <th>Produto</th>
    <th>valor</th>
    <th>Status</tr>
</tr>
 <?php
    foreach( $pedidos as $pedido) {
        foreach($pedido as $row){
?>
<tr>
<?php 
    if(isset($row['rowspan']) && $row['rowspan']>1){
             echo  '<td rowspan=" ' . $row['rowspan'] .'">'.$row['order_id'].'</td>';     
    }
    if(isset($row['rowspan']) && $row['rowspan'] === 1){
            echo  '<td>'.$row['order_id'].'</td>';     
        }
   ?>
  <td><?php echo $row['mark']. " " .$row['model']; ?></td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td><?php echo number_format($row['price'], 2, '.', ','); ?> </td>
  <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
        } ?>
</table>
```